# How to disable the dropdownlist in DetailView depending on the date?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a `DropDownList` in the `DetailView` (EditMode) and I would like to disable it depending on the date of the system.
For example : between the 18 June and the 20 June, make the dropdownlist *disabled* (gray).

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried some coding so far?? Show us your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DisableTime(new DateTime(2014,5,1),new DateTime(2014,10,1));
    }

    private void DisableTime(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
        if (currentTime > startTime && currentTime < endTime)
        {
            this.DropDownList1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

if use DetailsView and EditTemplate , try it in DetailsView_PreRender or DetailsView_ItemCreated event to find DropdownList control like below

```
  protected void DetailsView1_ItemCreated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = DetailsView1.FindControl("your dropdownlist id") as DropDownList;

        ddl.Enabled = false;
    }
```

Comment: The dropdown seems to be in a detailsview. So he might need to find the control in the detailsview before he will be able to modify the `Enabled` property.